# Auth to two separate systems

Tags: c#, security

Is it possible to authenticate a user to two systems when you only can control one system - *in a secure fashion*?

I have reasently got a request to share user information across two web systems, let's call the systems A and B.

I can control system A, and to authenticate to it the implimentation is currently BankID - https://www.bankid.com/en/

Here is a pucture for illustration:
[image]

**Request:**
If the user exists in system A, when the user clicks a link inside system A - redirect the user to system B and bypass the authentication to system B. Else force the user to create a payed account to system B.

Can this be done in a secure fashion when you can't control system B?

*Sidenote:*
The programming language that is beeing used is C# and system A and system B does not share servers and databases. I can see flaws in sharing user information across multiple systems and bypassing authentications.

Comment: SSO? Would need to share User information...https://github.com/IdentityServer

Comment: To use single sign on, don't you need a parent domain for both websites? The sites are on different domain.

Comment: Yes, hosted app like anything else but lets face it for security it's awesome... both your apps would talk to the Identity Server. Domain A and Domain B will not need to know about each other. Don't get me wrong it's a steep learning curve but very rewarding.

Comment: Yeah I thought about haveing an API of some sort that both apps auth through. But the problem is I can only manage one of the systems, and I also don't think the customer wants to change from BankID-authentication or even invest too much in security hence it's just a minor membership site.